# How to display date in specific format

Tags: php, mysql

I have a date field that I would like to express through a MySQL Query or as a PHP function as yyyymmdd, basically without any - or /, all the examples I can find include these.

I could build it a piece at a time, so y.m.d, but thought someone here might have come across this for, its basically a naming convention for network folders, hence why no special characters.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can use PHP's DateTime Class:

```
echo (new DateTime($dateField))->format('Ymd');
```

Answer (score 1):

**SQL** you can use [DATE_FORMAT](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-date_format/)

```
DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y%m%d') //20150513
```

**PHP** you can use using [date](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

```
echo date('Ymd'); //20150513
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [strtotime()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) and [date()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function like this:

```
$time = strtotime($yourdatefield);
$date = date('Ymd', $time);
```